# Creating a limit to find the sum of array values to a set number Numpy Python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, sum

I want to make a function where the sum of the `Arrays` and `Arrays2` array is equivalent to `val`. The function should modify the `Arrays` and `Arrays2` values so that the last index will output the sum of all values in the array to be `val`. How will be able to get the Expected Output?

```
import numpy as np 

Arrays = np.array([50, 30, 25, 87, 44, 68, 45])
Arrays2 = np.array([320])
val = 300
```

Expected output:

```
[50, 30, 25, 87, 44, 64]
[300]
```

Comment: Where does the `64` come from in your expected output?

Comment: Please explain better the expected output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

something like this?

```
import numpy as np 

Arrays = np.array([50, 30, 25, 87, 44, 68, 45])
Arrays2 = np.array([320])
val = 300


def thisRareFunction(arr):

    outArrays = []
    acum = 0
    for x in arr:
        acum += x
        if acum <=val:
            outArrays.append(x)
        else:
            outArrays.append(x -(acum-val))
            break
    return outArrays

print(thisRareFunction(Arrays))
print(thisRareFunction(Arrays2))
```